# Not able to import the variable from a compiled library in Javascript Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

This is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "deep-playground-prototype",
  "version": "2016.3.10",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "start": "npm run serve-watch",

    "prep": "browserify src/csv.ts -p [tsify] | uglifyjs -c > csv.js && copyfiles analytics.js dist && concat node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.js node_modules/seedrandom/seedrandom.min.js csv.js > dist/lib.js",
    "build-css": "copyfiles fonts.css dist && concat node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.css styles.css > dist/bundle.css",
    "watch-css": "concat node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.css styles.css -o dist/bundle.css",
    "build-html": "copyfiles index.html dist",
    "watch-html": "concat index.html -o dist/index.html",
    "watch-js": "watchify src/playground.ts -p [tsify] -v --debug -o dist/bundle.js",
    "build-js": "browserify src/playground.ts -p [tsify] | uglifyjs -c > dist/bundle.js",
    "build": "npm run prep && npm run build-js && npm run build-css && npm run build-html",
    "watch": "npm run prep && concurrently \"npm run watch-js\" \"npm run watch-css\" \"npm run watch-html\"",
    "serve": "http-server -o -c-1 dist/",
    "serve-watch": "concurrently \"http-server -o -c-1 dist/\" \"npm run watch\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/d3": "^3.5.41",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "concurrently": "3.1.0",
    "copyfiles": "1.0.0",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "tsify": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9",
    "uglify-js": "^2.8.29",
    "watchify": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.27",
    "csv-parse": "^4.2.0",
    "csvtojson": "^2.0.8",
    "d3": "^3.5.16",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^2.2.1",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "seedrandom": "^2.4.3",
    "typings": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

The csv.ts file is:

```
import {csv} from 'd3';
async function delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms) );
}
export let train = [];
(async()=>{console.log('before delay');csv("training.csv",function(error,data){train = data});await delay(1000);console.log('after delay')})();
```

I am trying to load data at first into a variable named `train`. Then I am trying to lad it from the `lib.js` file into the program:

```
import {train} from 'lib';
```

But getting the following error after compilation:

> TypeScript error: src/dataset.ts(17,21): Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'lib'.

I have missed something in this process.

Comment: Check your lib file exist 
and
you are importing it in your main HTML file

Comment: It exists while compilation it is getting created. You can see that in my `package.json` file. Let me know if you have any other queries. Please let me know what I can do.

Comment: where are you importing lib.js file

Comment: You see this in my question: `import {train} from 'lib';`

Comment: What I understood is lib.js is a newly constructed file. 
It's not a module. Hence, you cannot import modules from js file like this.

Comment: Try import {train} from 'csv'; as it defined in csv

Comment: So do you have any idea what I can do in that case because I am not getting what I can do to load the csv first and then rest of my program follows.

Comment: I tried that. But it will return empty array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185416/discussion-between-jaffer-wilson-and-harsh-chaurasia).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you change your module loading logic, you will probably need a relative import path:

```
import { train } from './lib'; // Assuming same folder, otherwise adjust path
```

`'lib'` works if it is a recognized module, e.g. a dependency installed to the `node_modules`.

Comment: Getting following error: `Error TS2307: Cannot find module './lib'.`

Comment: Do you have a compiled type declaration file (`lib.d.ts`)?

Comment: No I didn't have that. I have mentioned that it is getting created through the package definition. As you can see that in my `package.json` which I mentioned in the question.

Comment: I am not familiar with browserify's option, but it should be somehow configurable that you can have it output one. This will be necessary if you want to use the module in TS.

Comment: ok so what I need to do in the `lib.d.ts`? Do I need to write only the references? If yes then how I can mention  it please let me know.

Comment: It should describe the API of the module, which can be generated automatically by the TypeScript compiler, you would only write these manually for code that has always been JS. For more information please read [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html).

Comment: The `tsc` flag for generating declarations is `--declaration`. How to make that work with your pipeline is up to you.